# EAS build in monorepo failure (Failed to construct transformer: Error: Cannot parse ) Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'

Tags: build, expo, monorepo, eas

Created a new starter template using `create-solito-app` and then tried to build the project with eas build but the build has failed, the log has been attached.
I'm trying this new approach of creating NextJs and Expo apps with shared code, but I'm unable to build the project. 
I have run the follow commands.

```
➜  npx create-solito-app@latest my-solito-app
➜  cd apps/expo 
➜  expo eas build --platform android
```

Following is the log from the eas build

```
Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
Unzipping /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9-all.zip to /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs
Set executable permissions for: /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/bin/gradle
Welcome to Gradle 6.9!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - This is a small backport release.
 - Java 16 can be used to compile when used with Java toolchains
 - Dynamic versions can be used within plugin declarations
 - Native support for Apple Silicon processors
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
> Configure project :expo-file-system
WARNING: Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
> Configure project :expo
Using expo modules
  - expo-application (4.0.2)
  - expo-constants (13.0.2)
  - expo-error-recovery (3.0.5)
  - expo-file-system (13.1.4)
  - expo-font (10.0.5)
  - expo-keep-awake (10.0.2)
- expo-modules-core (0.6.5)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.14.2)
  - react-native-reanimated (2.3.3)
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
[stderr] Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Welcome to Metro!
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated
[stderr] Failed to construct transformer:  Error: Cannot parse /home/expo/.nvm/test/fast/Unit tests/mocks/project_dirs/nested-both/package.json as JSON: Unexpected end of JSON input
[stderr]     at Object.worker (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:146:13)
[stderr]     at HasteMap._processFile (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:724:8)
[stderr]     at HasteMap._buildHasteMap (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:776:28)
[stderr]     at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:426:33
[stderr] error Cannot parse /home/expo/.nvm/test/fast/Unit tests/mocks/project_dirs/nested-both/package.json as JSON: Unexpected end of JSON input.
Error: Cannot parse /home/expo/.nvm/test/fast/Unit tests/mocks/project_dirs/nested-both/package.json as JSON: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Object.worker (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:146:13)
    at HasteMap._processFile (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:724:8)
    at HasteMap._buildHasteMap (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:776:28)
    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:426:33
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
[stderr] > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 2m 1s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: Cannot parse /home/expo/.nvm/test/fast/Unit tests/mocks/project_dirs/nested-both/package.json as JSON: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

it looks like there is an invalid `package.json` in your project. you should check that file and validate that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding developmentClient to the eas.build fixed it. but I don't know how to do it without. Perhaps some libraries are requiring tests from jest and that is the cause...